# TBXML doesn't parse tag with special character as value

Tags: ios, xml, tbxml

I'm trying to parse an `XML` using `TBXML` and everything is going fine except for tags which contain special characters in their value.

For example, consider the XML element
`<tag> sources/data </tag>`

I'm trying to get the text `sources/data` from this tag. I'm using `[TBXML textForElement:element]` to achieve this. But it always returns an empty string. 
The same code fails for another tag which is defined as :
`<tag> array[i] </tag>`.

But it works fine for normal text values like
`<tag>name</tag>`.

Can anyone help me out here ?

Answer (score 0):

Quote: "`Because XML syntax uses some characters for tags and attributes it is not possible to directly use those characters inside XML tags or attribute values.`"

http://www.dvteclipse.com/documentation/svlinter/How_to_use_special_characters_in_XML.3F.html

As I know this kind of data must be in placed CDATA.